# id_token is malformed when calling refresh token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

As part of our Azure API Management set up we are using oAuth 2.0 combined with Active Directory.

we are using the **id_token** (JWT) to authenticate, which is working well.

we can request an **id_token** via the redirect url (microsoft login) and this token can be used to call our API successfully (validated again our API policy).

The problem occurs when we want to refresh the token.

We follow this process:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens

[image: Refresh Token Request]

As you can see, i get an **id_token** back (because the scope *openid* is passed) but the problem is, the **id_token** is malformed.

Instead of making up of **3** parts  e.g.  **AAAA.BBBB.CCCC**

The **id_token** returned, only has **2** parts (missing the signature)  e.g. **AAAA.BBBB.**

when using this **id_token** to authenticate, it obviously fails :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the id_token only has two parts but isn't it the access token that you should be sending to authorize requests? Perhaps the id_token was working earlier because it was signed by the proper authorization server but should have been the access token all along? It's the access token that's supposed to be refreshed after all.

I assume you sent "offline_access" as one of your scopes when you originally got your valid id_token, access_token, and refresh_token or you shouldn't have received an refresh_token. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6 says that if you provide a scope on the refresh request, your access token shouldn't be limited to the scope(s) provided in the refresh request. The openid connect spec (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokenResponse) says that a refresh request is like the token request except it "might not contain an id_token". It seems to me that all bets are off when it comes to expecting the id_token in the refresh response unless it's an implementation-specific feature in Azure.

Update
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#refresh-the-access-token

"id_token--An unsigned JSON Web Token (JWT). The app can base64Url decode the segments of this token to request information about the user who signed in. The app can cache the values and display them, but it should not rely on them for any authorization or security boundaries. For more information about id_tokens see the v2.0 endpoint token reference."

Notice it's unsigned. That's your missing third part of the jwt.

Comment: Agreed, typically the access token is what is refreshed. but i would assume, if an id token wasn't meant to be returned. there wouldn't be an id token rather then there being a malformed one. passing a scope of **openid** is what determines that i want an id token.

Comment: i'm holding on to the fact that the open-id specification says 'it *might* not contain an id_token' and leaning on the fact that a token has been sent .vs no token at all. chances are, the azure oauth2.0 implementation is faulty (heaven forbid!) and an id_token shouldn't be returned.

Comment: I think I found a more complete answer from Azure. See the updated answer. Essentially Azure returns an unsigned JWT...That's why there are only two parts

Comment: @Mike I ran into same problem recently. I see that you also have access_token and refresh_token to be same value. I was expecting access_token to  be a valid jwt which it clearly isn't . That forced me to use id_token as bearer token , which is not it's intended purpose.  I see that id_token is expected to be unsigned on refreshing.   How did you circumvent the issue?

Comment: @NewtonCode Did you ever find an answer?